# How to make logs in application insight without using Task.Delay method?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace))
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService("Application_Key");

        static IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        static ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("AppointmentPatientCommunication"))
            {
                logger.LogInformation("1st");
                hero();
                logger.LogError("2nd");
                telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Here is the error");
                telemetryClient.Flush();

            }
        }
        static void hero()
        {
            using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("AppointmentPatientCommunication"))
            {
                logger.LogInformation("2nd");
                telemetryClient.Flush();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I uploading this console application as my webjob to make a log in application insight. I am trying to avoid the use of `task.delay()` so that I can get real-time logging at perfect timing. I am uploading this webjob triggered manually, but I see no entry in my application insights. Could anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Logs are entering only using while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491672/why-logs-are-entering-only-using-while-loop)

Comment: @PeterBons Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telemetry is not sent instantly. Telemetry items are batched and sent by the ApplicationInsights SDK. In Console apps, which exits right after calling Track() methods, telemetry may not be sent unless Flush() and Sleep/Delay is done before the app exits as shown in full example later in this article. Sleep is not required if you are using InMemoryChannel. There is an active issue regarding the need for Sleep which is tracked here: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/407).

So there are two types of channels: InMemoryChannel and ServerTelemetryChannel
For more details about the both the channels click on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/telemetry-channels).

In my program to deal with the issue, I used InMemoryChannel. In the below code, I have shown a portion of code to show how I added it in my program.

```
static IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace))
        .AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel), new InMemoryChannel())
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService("Application_Key");
```

The Nuget Package I am using is `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ [Peter Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons) for your comment, Which helps to fix the problem.

The **Flush()** method in the **Telemetry Client** is used to flush the in-**memory buffer** when the application is shutting down. Normally, the SDK delivers data every **30 seconds** or when the buffer is full (500 items), and there is no need to invoke the **Flush()** method manually for web applications unless the program is ready to be shut down.

- The **TelemetryClient** object's **Flush()** method sends all of the data it presently holds in a buffer to the App Insights service.
- **Application Insights** will transfer your data in **batches** in the ***background*** to make better use of the network.
- In most cases, you won't need to call **Flush()**. However, if you know the process will leave after that point, you should execute **Flush()** to ensure that all of the ***data gets transmitted***.

Here, I have added the **Thread.Sleep();** call after the Flush Statement.

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("AppointmentPatientCommunication"))
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("1st");
                    hero();
                    logger.LogError("2nd");
                    telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Here is the error");
                      # Flush takes some times to memory buffer at the shutdown activity.
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                    # By default Flush takes 30 Sec so you have to wait for 30 sec.
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                }
            }
            static void hero()
            {
                using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("AppointmentPatientCommunication"))
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("2nd");
                    # Flush takes some times to memory buffer at the shutdown activity.
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                    # By default Flush takes 30 Sec so you have to wait for 30 sec.
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                }
            }
```

#### Results in AI:

[image]

Comment: I can't use Thread.Sleep(2000) for production purposes. I guess it will mess up when the application will run in real-time.

Comment: If we use **Telemetry.Flush()** we need to need to use **Thread.sleep** or **Task.Delay** to complete it. Because the Flush() call isn't **synchronous**.

Comment: ```telemetryClient.FlushAsync();``` I'll try using this one then.

Comment: yes, you can use it.

Comment: Well in the case of ```telemetryClient.FlushAsync(cancellation token);```  I need to use cancellation token which I don't know in my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243017/discussion-between-delliganeshs-mt-and-psychonaut007).

Comment: I tried using task.async but the situation is still the same. i am still looking for answer on internet.

Comment: ```Task.Delay(5000).Wait();  telemetryClient.Flush();``` I have to use this to make a log I don't understand how Microsoft is trying to make it better for the cloud rather than making physical logs in notepad. By the way, I am still looking for the efficient way.

Comment: Any idea how can I use InMemoryChannel in this program?