# Why Logs are entering only using while loop?

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stoptwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stoptwatch.Start();
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            //var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
            // Being a regular console app, there is no appsettings.json or configuration providers enabled by default.
            // Hence instrumentation key and any changes to default logging level must be specified here.
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace));
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService("appkey");
            //services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(aiOptions);
            // Build ServiceProvider.
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Obtain logger instance from DI.
            ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

            // Obtain TelemetryClient instance from DI, for additional manual tracking or to flush.
            var telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

            int i = 0;
            
                // Replace with a name which makes sense for this operation.
                using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(""))
                {
                    telemetryClient.TrackTrace("VS OK This is tracktrace from telemetry" + i);//
                    logger.LogWarning("VS OK Logger.logWarning" + i);//
                    logger.LogInformation("VS OK logger.LogInformation" + i);
                    logger.LogTrace("VS OK logger.LogTrace" + i);
                    logger.LogError("VS OK logger.LogError" + i);//
                    logger.LogDebug("VS OK logger.LogDebug" + i);
                    logger.LogCritical("VS OK logger.LogCritical" + i);//
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                }
                
        }
    }
}
```

When I uploading this program in my web job and running query:

traces
| sort by timestamp desc
| where message contains "OK"

I can't see any log entry but when I modify my program and add either infinite while loop or while loop running till 10 like below, only then I can see my logs get entered.

```
while(true)
{
using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(""))
                {
                    telemetryClient.TrackTrace("VS OK This is tracktrace from telemetry" + i);//
                    logger.LogWarning("VS OK Logger.logWarning" + i);//
                    logger.LogInformation("VS OK logger.LogInformation" + i);
                    logger.LogTrace("VS OK logger.LogTrace" + i);
                    logger.LogError("VS OK logger.LogError" + i);//
                    logger.LogDebug("VS OK logger.LogDebug" + i);
                    logger.LogCritical("VS OK logger.LogCritical" + i);//
                    telemetryClient.Flush();
                }
}
```

Comment: `Flush` does take some time. Try adding a call to `Thread.Sleep(2000);` as the last line in your first example.

Comment: I can't use ```Thread.Sleep(2000)``` for production purposes. I guess it will mess up when the application will run in real-time.

Comment: Why? You will only need to call flush at the end of the process, when it is about to shutdown.

Comment: Actually, I am manually triggering webjob so I believe I will be needing flush I guess to make sure logs get entered before program shutdowns. I am trying to avoid ```Task.Delay().wait()``` to make sure the program doesn't crash if the application runs in real-time

Answer (score 0):

It will work in both places not only specific to Loop. You have to wait for **30sec** after the **Flush()** happens.

> #### Note:
>
> The **Flush()** method in the **Telemetry Client** is used to flush the in-**memory buffer** when the application is shutting down. Normally, the SDK delivers data every **30 seconds** or when the buffer is full (500 items), and there is no need to invoke the **Flush()** method manually for web applications unless the program is ready to be shut down.

After **Flush()** you have to wait by using Either **Thread.Sleep()** or **Task.Delay().wait()** which follows:

```cs
# Flush takes some times to memory buffer at the shutdown activity.
telemetryClient.Flush();

# By default Flush takes 30 Sec so you have to wait for 30 sec.
Thread.Sleep(3000);
# or
Task.Delay().wait();
```

#### Result:

Without Loop
[image]

With Loop
[image]

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490948/how-to-make-logs-in-application-insight-without-using-task-delay-method) for continuation

Comment: Hey @Psychonaut007! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?